# Cant Render 2 different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having problem rendering components. I have App Component which is the main component it has its root/id which is located in index.js which renders fine. But the problem is in SystemSidebar it has its own root/id but when I try to render it gives me this error. The target container is not a DOM element.

```
System Sidebar Component 
class SystemSidebar extends Component {

  render(){
    
    return (
     
        <div id='b' >
           
        <Router>
          <MainSystem/>
        <Switch>
         <Route exact  path="Sound" component={Sound}/>
         <Route exact path="Display" component={Display}/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Settings} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
       </div>
  )
  }  
}

export default SystemSidebar


App Component
class App extends Component {

render(){
  return (
    <div id='a' className="App">
        <div>
         <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
             <Route  exact path="/MainSystem" component={MainSystem}/>
             <Route exact path="/BlueTooth" component={BlueTooth}/>
             <Route exact path="/" component={Settings} />
           </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    </div>

  );
  }
}

export default App;


index.js

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
<App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('a')
);



ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
<SystemSidebar />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('b')
);
```

Comment: I do not see where you attached the components to the document of your index.html. `document.getElementById('a')` did not return a dom-node because thats the id of your App that is not yet attached to the dom tree. I don't know the html file you use your react scripts in, so I can not help you what to use instead of 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your Components in the main component which is `App` because it's the root for `ReactJs`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render two components with renderDOM method then you have to create that element in html file first. But it's not good practice to do that, since you can't share state between those two.

index.html

```
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="root2"></div>
  </body>
```

index.js

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const rootElement2 = document.getElementById("root2");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SystemSidebar />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement2
);
```

Comment: it renders them on top of each other

Comment: I want Systemsidebar to render on a different page

Comment: if you want to render them next to each other them put Sidebar Component i App Component and use only one RenderDOM. Eventually if you reeally want to do like than then you can easily give styling to your components to behave like that

Comment: what do you mean on different page? On different pathname or what?

Comment: System Sidebar has a Navbar which is MainSystem. I want when I click on the MainSystem  item for example Display it redirect me to the Display page.